# Calling function on a separate page than current in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console.log

I have a function that I'm running in a browser console.

```
function answer(){

  console.log(document.querySelector("#qti-choiceinteraction-container > tbody > tr.checkedrow > td.answer > div > label > span > p"));

}
```

Clearly, it is printing some text from an element on the page I'm currently. The thing is, I want to query on a different page, not the current page(document).

How would I call the `querySelector` method on a different page, instead of document, if I have the URL of the page I want to run it on?

Comment: @jeffkmeng While it is a duplicate, the original question has obsolete answers.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher — It isn't locked. New answers can be posted to it. That way when people find the old question instead of this duplicate on a search they'll get the new answers.

Comment: @Quentin Except that few people actually go through and answer old questions... its a flaw of stack overflow.   It's sexier to answer recent questions.  It takes a moderator to combine answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page is on the same domain, or doesn't have cross-domain restrictions, `fetch` the response text from that URL, then parse it into a document with `DOMParser`, and then you can use `querySelector` on that document:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((responseText) => {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(responseText, 'text/html');
    console.log(doc.querySelector("#qti-choiceinteraction-container > tbody > tr.checkedrow > td.answer > div > label > span > p"));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // There was an error, handle it here
  });
```

If the page is on a different domain *and* has (common) cross-domain restrictions, then the only way to bypass those restrictions is to bounce the request off of a server instead. (Have your script make a request to the server, have the server make the request to the other site, then have the server send the response back to your script.)

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the element into the function. I assume your function is more complex than this example, which you don't need a function for.

```js
function answer(element){
    console.log(element);
}

answer(document.querySelector(".myDiv"))
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```